# Julia sparse matrix with random 1's

Tags: random, julia, sparse-matrix

So I have a size N in julia and I need an NxN sparse matrix with N ones in it, in random places. What would be the best way to go about this?

At first I thought about randomly generating indexes and then setting those numbers to 1 in a sparse matrix but I recently found the sprand functions however I don't understand how to use them correctly or apply them to my problem. I tried using it with my limited understanding and it keeps generating error messages. Help is of course always greatly appreciated :)

Comment: `sprand`.......

Comment: `sparse(rand(1:N, N), rand(1:N, N), ones(N), N, N)` will do it

Comment: this does not always work as you can get some (i,j) repeated several times thus getting a matrix with less nonzero elements than expected.

Comment: True. Added an answer which is more complex but fixes the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by @DanGetz comment above, the following solution is a one-line function using `randperm`. I deleted the original answer as it was not very helpful.

```
sparseN(N) = sparse(randperm(N), randperm(N), ones(N), N, N)
```

This is also incredibly fast:

```
@time sparseN(10_000);
  0.000558 seconds (30 allocations: 782.563 KiB)
```

Comment: Does this guarantee no re-use of the same i,j tuple?

Comment: Yes, it will never repeat any indices, since `randperm` permutes `1:N` unique values.

Answer (score 1):

A sparse matrix of dimension (N rows)x(M columns) has at most NxM components that can be indexed using the K=[0,N*M) integer set. For any k in K you can retrieve element indices (i,j) thanks to a Euclidean division k = i + j*N (here column major layout).

To randomly sample n elements of K (**without** repetition), you can use Knuth algorithm "Algorithm S (Selection sampling technique)" 3.4.2, in its book [Vol2., seminumerical-Algorithms](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201896842)

In Julia:

```
function random_select(n::Int64,K::Int64) 
    @assert 0<=n<=K

    sample=Vector{Int64}(n)
    t=Int64(0)
    m=Int64(0)

    while m<n
        if (K-t)*rand()>=n-m
            t+=1
        else
            m+=1
            sample[m]=t
            t+=1
        end
    end
    sample
end
```

The next part simply retrieves the I,J indices to create the sparse matrix from its coordinate form:

```
function create_sparseMatrix(n::Int64,N::Int64,M::Int64)
    @assert (0<=N)&&(0<=M)
    @assert 0<=n<=N*M

    nonZero = random_select(n,N*M)

    # column major: k=i+j*N
    I = map(k->mod(k,N),nonZero)
    J = map(k->div(k,N),nonZero)

    sparse(I+1,J+1,ones(n),N,M)
end
```

**Usage example:** a 4x5 sparse matrix with 3 nonzero (=1.0) at random positions:

```
julia> create_sparseMatrix(3,4,5)
4×5 SparseMatrixCSC{Float64,Int64} with 3 stored entries:
  [4, 1]  =  1.0
  [3, 2]  =  1.0
  [3, 3]  =  1.0
```

**Border case tests:**

```
julia> create_sparseMatrix(0,4,5)
4×5 SparseMatrixCSC{Float64,Int64} with 0 stored entries

julia> create_sparseMatrix(4*5,4,5)
4×5 SparseMatrixCSC{Float64,Int64} with 20 stored entries:
  [1, 1]  =  1.0
  [2, 1]  =  1.0
  [3, 1]  =  1.0
  [4, 1]  =  1.0
  ⋮
  [4, 4]  =  1.0
  [1, 5]  =  1.0
  [2, 5]  =  1.0
  [3, 5]  =  1.0
  [4, 5]  =  1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Insisting on a one-line-ish solution:

```
using StatsBase
sparseones(N,M,K) = sparse(
  (x->(first.(x).+1,last.(x).+1))(divrem.(sample(0:N*M-1,K,replace=false),M))...,
  ones(K),N,M
)
```

Giving:

```
julia> sparseones(3,4,5)
3×4 SparseMatrixCSC{Float64,Int64} with 5 stored entries:
  [1, 1]  =  1.0
  [2, 1]  =  1.0
  [3, 3]  =  1.0
  [2, 4]  =  1.0
  [3, 4]  =  1.0
```

This method is essentially the same as the earlier answer with the advantage of re-using existing `sample` and being much shorter. It is even faster on larger matrices.